# Pass parameter to pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I am passing parameter to pig with the bellow command

> pig -x local -f fmipSl.pig -param day=20111013 -param
>   "date='13-OCT-2011 00:00:00'"

But its not working.

Showing error

> Lexical error at line 1, column 18.  Encountered:  after :
>   "\'13-OCT-2011".

I have also tried

> pig -x local -f fmipSl.pig -param day=20111013 -param
>   "date=13-OCT-2011\ 00:00:00"

Which giving

```
Unexpected internal error. String index out of range: 12.
```

Please Help

Comment: Using pig version 0.8.1

Comment: can you show the piece of script that's using your $date parameter? Also, why don't you switch to a newer pig version?